# Error bound of midpoint rules with unbounded second derivative

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

It is well known that error bound of midpoint rule for function $f[a,b]$ is given by
$$
E\leq K\frac{(b-a)^3}{24 n^2}
$$
where $|f(x)''\leq K|$ and $n$ is the number of time steps.

if second derivative is not bounded, midpoint rule does not converge?

For example, $f(x)=\sqrt x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.

if convergent, what is error bound of such functions?

Comment: Midpoint rule is approximating the integral by $$\sum_{k = 1}^n f\biggl(\frac{x_k + x_{k-1}}{2}\biggr)\cdot (x_k - x_{k-1}),$$ or is there more to it? With an integrable $f$, that converges to the integral, just in general not as fast as for twice differentiable $f$ with bounded second derivative.

Comment: If we say that a function $f$ is $r=n+\alpha$ regular when $f^{(n)}$ is $\alpha$-Holder, I would expect that the error is some constant times $\frac{(b-a)^{r+1}}{n^r}$.

Comment: I expect one can prove a bound
$$
E \leq C \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)^2 \int_{a+O(n^{-1})}^b \left|f''(x)\right| dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the second derivative being unbounded means that the midpoint rule does not converge. But it does mean that *this method of estimating the error* doesn't tell you anything about the convergence.

In such cases, you must either use a different approximation method or be more clever about your current application. In practice, approximating $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt x dx$ using the midpoint rule converges (although a bit slower than some other quadrature rules).

We can accentuate the problems evident here. If you were to look at
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{100x^{.99}}dx = 1$$
using the midpoint rule, you would encounter *extremely slow* convergence. On the one hand, it *does* converge (generally speaking, we should expect convergence for any continuous monotone function). But even breaking up the interval into 1000 pieces leaves enormous error.